# How to create same bean with different configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my bean configuration class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:gerrit.properties" })
public class BeanConfig {

    @Value("${gerrit.user}")
    public String gerritUser;

    @Value("${gerrit.pass}")
    public String gerritPass;

    @Value("${gerrit.url}")
    public String gerritUrl;

    @Value("${proxy.ip}")
    public String proxyIp;

    @Value("${proxy.port}")
    public String proxyPort;

    @Bean(name="gerritRestClient")  
    public GerritRestClient getGerritRestClient(){      
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1");
        GerritAuthData.Basic authData=new GerritAuthData.Basic(gerritUrl, gerritUser,gerritPass);
        HttpRequestExecutor httpRequestExecutor=new HttpRequestExecutor();      
        GerritRestClient gerritRestClient=new GerritRestClient(authData,new HttpRequestExecutor());         
        return gerritRestClient;        
    }


}
```

In gerrit.properties I have a different gerrit url ( property name gerrit.service.url).
So I need to form a bean of type GerritRestClient to make use of the other gerrit. Both the beans are required for my app
Gerrit Rest CLient is a github project which is a java client for gerrit.

in my Service code I am autowiring the bean as following

```
@Autowired
private GerritRestClient gerritRestClient;
```

How to create a different bean with the other url from properties file
 of type GerritRestClient  and how to inject it

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to qualify the bean: your first bean has name `gerritRestClient`. Make other bean with a different name to create second one with different configuration. Inject a different one by using `@Qualifier` annotation with appropriate name.

Comment: Hi! Have you heard about @Qualifier? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm
This seems the thing you're looking for

Comment: It would be more optimal to keep using the same client bean but use a full URL for service requests. Don't know if that's possible though.

Comment: After creation of bean its  not possible to change the url..  So implementing Qualifier ````@Bean(name="gerritSearchClient") 
 public GerritRestClient getGerritSearchClient()
  GerritAuthData.Basic authData=new GerritAuthData.Basic(gerritUrlsearch, gerritUser,gerritPass);
  HttpRequestExecutor httpRequestExecutor=new HttpRequestExecutor();  
  GerritRestClient gerritRestClient=new GerritRestClient(authData,new HttpRequestExecutor());   
  return gerritRestClient;  
 }````  Injecting as ````@Autowired
 @Qualifier("gerritRestClient")
 private GerritRestClient gerritSearchClient;````